# What does Moq's use of "m=>m.FooEvent+=null" mean?

Tags: c#, moq

What is the meaning behind the first argument in mock.Raise? I recognize that it's a lambda, but I am uncertain why Moq needs a lambda that tries to add a null EventHandler to an event.

```
// Raising an event on the mock
mock.Raise(m => m.FooEvent += null, new FooEventArgs(fooValue));
```

Comment: I would guess that first argument is an expression tree and outside the defining class the only usage allowed for an event is via the add or remove operators (+=/-=). Moq probably just analyzes the expression tree for the event access doesn't really care what the delegate is, so null is fine.

Comment: Ah that's not quite it. It's not an expression tree, just a standard delegate  where an internal fake is passed so that Moq can analyze the call graph, but the main point still stands. This kind of add/remove operation is the only legal way to use an event outside the declaring type.

Comment: @mikez That was my first thought, too. However, the argument is `Action<T>` rather than `Expression`, so it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Rob Yea I was looking at source code too. It looks like an internal mock/fake is generated to analyze what the last event signup was.

Comment: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To raise an event from a mock object we use its Raise method. This
>   accepts two parameters. The first is a lambda expression that includes
>   an empty event subscriber for the event to raise. Although not the
>   most elegant syntax, this is required to allow Moq to understand how
>   the event is used. The second parameter provides the event arguments
>   that will be included with the event.

Taken from [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqEvents_2.aspx).

If we will look at Raise method in [moq source code](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/54dd9dc917afd5885c54e99aea9efd89c159d438/Source/Mock.Generic.cs), it's signature looks like this:

```
public void Raise(Action<T> eventExpression, EventArgs args);
```

It will uses `Action<T>` to identify which event we want to raise (using reflection), we specify this event using a lambda expression that is evaluated to some kind of delegate (`Action<T>`).

A better syntax will looks something like this:

```
mock.Raise(m => m.FooEvent, new FooEventArgs(fooValue));
```

But this lambda will not compile since it's not an `Action<T>`, consider this method which is our lambda equivalent:

```
public void Baz(SomeMock m)
{
    m.FooEvent;
}
```

it's signature seems to be valid, it has an input and no output which is such as `Action<T>` **BUT** this method will not compile, you can't access an event (or any property) without doing some operation on it (set, get, etc...) it is not supported in C# syntax, because of this reason moq writers needed to look for an alternative and they have chosen to use null event handler registration as a workaround to allow this lambda to be compiled:

```
m.FooEvent += null
```